# How to remove non-alphanumeric characters in SQL using Regex methods?

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-redshift

I want to strip all non-alphanumeric characters after the last alphanumeric character in one of my columns.

Sample Input:

```
my_column
weofneow.ewfiew')
wefkpfn.ewoifnw)
wepfnfe.ewfipn;
```

Sample Output:

```
my_column
weofneow.ewfiew
wefkpfn.ewoifnw
wepfnfe.ewfipn
```

My code right now looks like:

```
SELECT replace(replace(my_column, '\'', ''), ')', '') 
FROM my_table
```

However, I keep finding cases with other non-alphanumeric characters at the end of my string, and want a simple (not using functions) and clean (probably using RegEx) way to strip them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) with a regex of `[^a-z0-9]+$`, replacing that with nothing. The regex will match any number of non-alphanumeric characters before the end of the string.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '[^a-z0-9]+$', '', 1, 'i')
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for! Is there an easy way to modify the regex part if I wanted to also strip any non-alphanumeric characters at the beginning? (e.g. `"wepfnfe.ewfipn;` --> `wepfnfe.ewfipn`)?